# Cancel button on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When the client click on Cancel (on ***ItemsOptions***) he should go back to the previous page (***Client***):

I added in the View ***ItemsOptions***:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("","", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="col-md-4"><input id = "theCancel" class="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" /></div>
}
```

When the Button Cancel is hit the error Message :

***The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.***

I added  in the controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ***Client***(OrderItems model)
{
}
```

and in the ***Client*** View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Client", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
}
```

I tried another way:

I added in the View ***ItemsOptions***:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("","", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", role = "form" }))
 {
   <div class="col-md-4"><input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Cancel" name="action:Cancel" /></div>
  }
```

the controller

```
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Cancel")]
public ActionResult Cancel(OrderItems model)
{
   return View("Client", model);
}
```

How can I implement the cancel button in the MVC form,I want the user to go to the previous page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the cancel button to go back

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function goBack() {
       window.history.back();
   }
</script>

<!--cancel button-->
<button onclick='goBack()'>Cancel</button>
```

Does something like this work for you?